# How to get list birthday in SQL Server or Linq?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I want to print out a list of 10 people who have birthday coming in SQL Server but i have not found a suitable solution. I have tried this but it does not work properly. Please help me.

SQL SERVER

```
SELECT TOP 5 NAME,   
             birthday, 
             Datediff(dd, people.birthday, Getdate()) / 365.00 / ( 
             Year(Getdate()) - Year(people.birthday) ) AS DAYS 
FROM   people 
WHERE  Datediff(dd, people.birthday, Getdate()) / 365.00 / ( 
              Year(Getdate()) - Year(people.birthday) ) <= 1 
ORDER  BY days DESC
```

LINQ

```
var query = 
   (from c in db.PEOPLEs 
    where ((DbFunctions.DiffDays(c.BIRTHDAY, DateTime.Now)/365.25/(DateTime.Now.Year - c.NGAYSINH.Year))<=1) 
    orderby (DbFunctions.DiffDays(c.BIRTHDAY, DateTime.Now)/365.00/(DateTime.Now.Year - c.BIRTHDAY.Year)) ascending   
    select c).Take(5);
```

Comment: Pleas do some effort to make the code readable. Also, giving some more details than *does not work properly* would help.

Comment: You want 10 people but your 2 queries returns 5 people (Top 5 and Take(5)). I didnt changed because I dont know your exact will (5 or 10 people...)

Comment: I don't understand your question. What do you mean? People who have birthday on the same day? All people who have birthday in the same week, same year erc? And what are the issues you found while trying to solve it? Please be more specific.Of course we can try to reverse-engineer your code, but it is easier if you describe what you wanted to do.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to print out a list of 10 people who have birthday coming

You can use the following LINQ query:

```
var query = db.PEOPLEs
    .OrderBy(p => p.Birthday.Month > DateTime.Now.Month ||
        (p.Birthday.Month == DateTime.Now.Month &&
         p.Birthday.Day >= DateTime.Now.Day) ? 0 : 1)
    .ThenBy(p => p.Birthday)
    .Take(10);
```

The trick is the conditional `OrderBy` which ensures incoming birthdates are before the pass birthdates.

Answer (score 0):

**UPD**

To consider dates in the next year the query has been rewritten:

```
Select Top 5 Name, BIRTHDAY
From People
Order by ABS( DATEDIFF( "d", BIRTHDAY, GETUTCDATE() ) ) DESC
```

This approach properly handles leap years and people born on 02/29.

Comment: What if today is near the end of the year?

Comment: Changed the query to consider the next year

Comment: Your query measures the difference in days between the current date and the birthDATE - note, not the month+day combination but the full date i.e. taking into account the day, month and *year* they were *born*. So the People will be sorted by their AGE and not by how close their next birthday is in the future.

Answer (score 0):

This will take into account end of the year etc.

```
select top 10 *
from People
order by (datepart(dy,Birthday)-datepart(dy,getdate())+365) % 365
```

It works by calculating the `dayofyear` for each birthday (from 1-365) relative to the current date's `dayofyear`, and uses modulo division (`%`) to bring the answer into the range 0-365 so that they can be sorted correctly. Therefore a birthday that was yesterday will be sorted on 365 and a birthday tomorrow will be sorted on 1.

Comment: what about leap years / people born on 29/02 ;-)

Comment: @ThomasG Actually it works for all cases, tested all combinations I could think of. Interestingly, T-SQL's `datepart(dy,@dateval)` returns 60 for both 3/1 and 2/29 so you could get birthdays on those two days coming out in the wrong order. I'll stand by this query unless you can show a counter-example!

Answer (score 0):

It's simple.
Just suppose that when is the person birthday in current year.
Then get difference days between the mentioned date and today.

Look at following sql-statement:

```
SELECT  TOP 10
        NAME,
        BIRTHDAY,
        DATEDIFF(DAY, GETDATE(), DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), MONTH(PEOPLE.BIRTHDAY), DAY(PEOPLE.BIRTHDAY))) AS RemainingDays
FROM    PEOPLE
WHERE   DATEDIFF(DAY, GETDATE(), DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), MONTH(PEOPLE.BIRTHDAY), DAY(PEOPLE.BIRTHDAY))) >= 0
ORDER   BY RemainingDays ASC
```